# How to debug precondition failure: invalid size for indirect attribute?

Tags: ios, swiftui

Error log can see here
https://ibb.co/F3RMJhS

Error seen in the console is "AttributeGraph precondition failure: invalid size for indirect attribute: 41 vs 0". Which happens in a view by this structure:

```
VStack{
    Form{
        Section{
            if x == 1{
                Group{}
                Group{}
            }else if x == 2{
                Group{}
                Group{}
            }else if x == 3{
                Group{}
                Group{}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This error happens when I scroll the view. How do I find this error location and later fix it? It happens only in IOS 14.2, and it works fine in IOS versions before that. Thank you.

Comment: The error might be due to internal views... I see your structure is too complex - try to separate those by small subviews, so under every condition will be only one subview.